# Gerrit - how to auto publish change after Jenkins run

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gerrit

I'm working with Git + Gerrit + Jenkins.
I would like Gerrit to automatically submit a change after Jenkins success run.
Is there any way to skip the review part (only verify is needed) and auto submit without user actions?

Comment: Can you suggest other tools for implementing continuous integration? I want every commit to trigger Jenkins and only after success run - merge the change so everyone can get it.

Comment: I would suggest setting up a development clone repo for each developer. Each developer can then have their own Jenkins jobs associated with their own work-stream (A more scalable way to do this is have a Jenkins instance running on each development PC). When you're ready to push code to the shared repo then you can decide whether you need Gerrit or not. In an ideal world you wouldn't push every single commit into Gerrit. Only the code ready for review.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that.

from the gerrit help pages.

http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.5.1/cmd-review.html

ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit review --verified +1 --code-review +2 --submit --project this/project commit

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. I did it using the Jenkins Gerrit plugin

Comment: The link is dead.