# Auto-submit reviews, if verified and approved

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I have Gerrit 2.5 server and Jenkins server (with Gerrit Trigger).

For some branches I configured Jenkins Gerrit Trigger so, that it not only verifies but also approves reviews, if the build and tests were successful.

My question is: How can I configure Gerrit or Jenkins so, that by Jenkins verified and approved review get merged automatically?

Tried solutions:

- Using "Post Build Task" Jenkins plugin add a script to merge reviews (as suggested in [Gerrit - how to auto publish change after Jenkins run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721653/gerrit-how-to-auto-publish-change-after-jenkins-run)). Problem: It merges builds with failing tests.
- Add Gerrit "comment-added" hook to check, if a review was verified and approved, then merge. Problem: It's complicated and it can't be configured well to auto-submit only from specified branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I found is to use Groovy Postbuild plugin. Following script executed after JUnit post build action does the trick:

```
if(manager.build.result.isBetterThan(hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE)) {
    def cmd = 'ssh -p 29418 HOST gerrit review --verified +1 --code-review +2 --submit --project $GERRIT_PROJECT $GIT_COMMIT'
    cmd = manager.build.environment.expand(cmd)
    manager.listener.logger.println("Merge review: '$cmd'")
    def p = "$cmd".execute()
    manager.listener.logger.println(p.in.text)
    manager.addShortText("M")
}
```

Your Jenkins account needs +1 verify, +2 review and submit permissions of course. You have also to set up public key authentication.

*On Windows*: You may use following command to run ssh from the git distribution

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -c "ssh -p 29418 HOST ..."
```

Comment: what's the content of $GIT_COMMIT ?

Comment: It should be the commit ID. You can print it out adding `manager.listener.logger.println("GIT_COMMIT : '$GIT_COMMIT'")`

Answer (score 3):

This is a currently working command for me using gerrit 2.10-rc0

```
if(manager.build.result.isBetterThan(hudson.model.Result.UNSTABLE)) {
    def cmd = 'ssh -p 29418 $host gerrit review --verified +1 --code --review +2 --submit $GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER,$GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER'
    cmd = manager.build.environment.expand(cmd)
    manager.listener.logger.println("Merge review: '$cmd'")
    def p = "$cmd".execute()
    manager.listener.logger.println(p.in.text)
    manager.addShortText("M")
}
```